# How to get the max of a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

I want to get the `id` of a row, based on max number that exists in `number` column on table `x`.

**For example:**
I have the following records inside `x` table.

```
 id      | number  
---------+---------
 9       | 289     
 10      | 100     
 24      | 187     
 54      | 345
```

I want a query to return the `id` **54** (`SELECT x.id ...`) by finding out that the **max of the column `number` is 345**.

How can I succeed that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query:

**Solution #1:**

```
SELECT 
x.*
FROM x
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
   MAX(number) AS max_number
  FROM x
) AS maxTable
ON x.number = maxTable.max_number
```

**Explanation:**

```
SELECT 
  MAX(number) AS max_number
FROM x;
```

**Result:**

**maxTable:**

```
max_number
   345
```

Now make an `inner join` between your table `x` and the above table named  `maxTable` on `maxTable.max_number` and `x.number`.

**x table:**

```
    =====================
    | id      | number  |
    =====================
    | 9       | 289     |
    ---------------------
    | 10      | 100     |
    ---------------------
    | 24      | 187     |
    ---------------------
    | 54      | 345     |
    ---------------------
```

Thus in the final output you will get only the entries which have `maxTable.max_number` in their `number` column.

**Solution #2:**

You can use `WHERE IN` to accomplish this too.

```
SELECT
*
FROM x
WHERE x.number IN ( SELECT MAX(number) FROM x )
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you do this as:

```
select t.id
from t
order by number desc
limit 1;
```